# c# for web games that use the GPU?? maybe WebGL?

Tags: c#, silverlight, opengl, gpu, webgl

I'm porting a game made for windows using OpenGL to silverlight, currently it's working, but the problem is that XNA/silverlight doesn't have the enough graphics performance, i think it is because XNA doesn't support the fixed pipeline (OpenGL does)

The windows version is like 4 to 5 times faster than the web version, and i know is fill rate bounded because when i make the browser bigger the game becomes terribly slow

Did you know any web platform that supports GPU and .net or a way to use OpenGL via silverlight?

Comment: The fixed function pipeline just means it's a pipeline that has a fixed set of functions/options as defined by the hardware...whereas shader based rendering allows complete flexibility .... http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline.

Comment: Have you enabled GPU acceleration with Silverlight? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: (yes its enabled) (i know that about the pipeline)

my game has very simple 2D graphics, and i want it to be available on a wide audience, without the need of dedicated graphics cards, etc... yet its has to be fast because the game is fast placed

Comment: and in some integrated gpus (like mine) the fixed pipeline it is faster than the programable pipeline, maybe its hardcoded right on the silicone

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into [Unity](http://unity3d.com/), I've seen it used by colleagues at university to make great-looking 3d games. Unfortunately the users must download the Web Player, but if you need the performance it's there.

Comment: Unity also has NaCL and Flash export options... though the web-player is very easy to install for the end user [I've done it in some pretty locked down environments no problem].

Comment: @OJ but it can easily give you a performance boost without any magic.

Comment: People can write slow code and slow algorithms regardless of the engine.

Comment: my graphics engine is fast and heavily optimized, It runs at 60 fps on my integrated gpu (no need for graphics card), i want it to be like the flash games you see on the internet, but better and faster, taking aproach of the gpu, and that's because i wan't the game to have very low specs, because it will be an internet game

Comment: my game is already written in c#, and it its graphics device independent, i can reuse .net dlls on unity??

Comment: I can't use unity :(, it seams that unity is based on polygon meshes, but my game generates triangles and indices on the fly. Does unity allows me to do something like DrawIndexedPrimives or glDrawElements???